# Capistrano - Best way to merge in Git?

Tags: git, merge, capistrano

Does capistrano have anything built in or an extension to perform merges?

would like to have a task that before deploying does a merge on 2 branches. i know i can write a task to do this but i'm new to capistrano and didn't know if there is something built in?

Answer (score 0):

```
set :destination, "the_branch_you_want_to_merge_to"
set :origin, "the_branch_you_want_to_merge_from"
set :merge_message, "your message"

run "git checkout #{destination}; git merge --squash #{origin}; git add . -A; git commit -m #{merge_message};"
```

But **i'll not recommend** this because you might break your cap deploy if ever you get any conflict in your merge ;)

Comment: thanks for the info. i'm aware i can write something myself but was wondering if cap had anything built in to handle the process in case of failures etc. apparently it appears like it doesn't which i find a little odd